# UITableViewCell (ReusableCell) are not Identifing correct constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I've used **Visual Format Language (VFL)** to set constraint of the UITableViewCustomCell's subviews.
its working fine when I scrolling my `TableView` slowly or normal speed.

But its now working when I scrolling `TableView` fast.

there are 3 different scenario comes.

TitleLabel --> one line text only
DetailTextLabel --> 0, 1 or 2 line only

#### see this screen shot which is looking correct when I scrolled it slowly

[image]

#### And when I scroll it fast then its not taking correct constraints

[image]

And one thing. Log does not displaying any warning. means that all constraints are complete and correct.

I've tried `[self updateConstraintsIfNeeded]`...etc so many things.

#### and its working correct when I used Different cell identifier for particular condition. but I don't want to use different-different cell Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

For Autolayout to work correctly it only requires that all constraints are set and that there are no conflicts amongst the constraints. If you fulfill these promises and ensure that your table view `rowHeight` property is set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (i.e. self-sizing cells), then everything should work properly. Also, a common mistake is to update the cell data inside of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. As stated in the documentation, the latter method gives the delegate to override state-based properties. Ensure that your table view is using [self sizing cells](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).

Comment: Yah **@Michael** My code dsnt have any conflicts constraints. and its working fine with both scenario...while slow/medium scrolling. but its mismatching the layout when I tried too fast up-down scroll. and your given link also have such problem. try it to fast up-down scroll...this will also give layout missing position. **I already referred this link** thanks for taking time for this problem